# favicon.ico appear in URL of submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, coldfusion, sql-injection

I'm not sure if this is SQL injection or not but occasionally in my error logs I will see the following (the domains have been x'd out for security):

Error 08/27/2013 04:34:39
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0 
Subject: example.Com Site Error-example.example.com-/league/298/action/registration/content_action/managedues/tabindex/3/m0dal_update/manageleague/submethod/record_payment/player_id/38195/f_division_id/1186/**dues_id/favicon.ico**
ERROR

I know for a fact I am passing the dues_id/*numericvalue* in that string. I also know for a fact that favicon.ico is absolutely NOWHERE in my code. Why does it appear in the URL string? Is it a javascript bug of some kind?

I am running on IIS7 Windows Server 2008 with Coldfusion 9 and Jquery 1.10.

Comment: A client is simply looking for `favicon.ico`.  Not sure why you think this has anything to do with SQL injection... what log are you seeing these in?  There isn't really enough context to help you with this question.

Comment: I don't know how my form action URL was changed and that string "favicon.ico" was put in place of a numerical value that was there. Wasn't sure if it was a bot or not.

Comment: @Brad I think he believes it's injection because he sees errors in is sql error log.  Not entirely sure but that's what I gathered from it.

Comment: In support of the OP, I do not think this is a request generated because the browser doesn't find an explicit favicon inclusion. I have seen the same behavior occasionally occurring, and it is put at the very END of the URL, that is after the query part of the URL with the encoded Request Parameters. It seems more like an accidental drag-n-drop into the URL, but then I see it only consistently happening in about 4 URL's out of many 1000's.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with SQL injection.  The browser is looking for a favicon.ico
Add the following line to your index page.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

And then make sure the image file is there.  You can create the icons easily at this website http://favicon-generator.org/

Comment: Might want to add this is a browser convention, not an attempt at SQL injection.

Comment: Correct.  Although I had implied this I have changed my answer to better communicate that fact. Thanks @doogle